How to get this Diophantine approximate lower bound?
Let infinite dimemsional integer vector $l=(l_j)_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\in\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{Z}$. And the set of index {$j|l_j\neq0$} is a finite set ($l$ is finite support).
$l$ also satisfying:

$l\neq0$
$l_j\neq l_{-j}$
$\sum_j jl_j\neq0$

Then is the formula:
$$|\sum_j(j^3+j\sqrt{\frac2\pi})l_j|$$
has a lower bound rely on |l|? I expect the bound will has a similar structure to $\frac c{e^{|l-k|}}$ or other function of $|l|$ decay, where
$|l|=\sum_j|l_j|<\infty$.
I guess there will be a lower bound because if $|\sum_j(j^3+j\sqrt{\frac2\pi})l_j|=0$ it means $|\sum_j j^3l_j|=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}|\sum_j jl_j|$
and LHS is integer but RHS is irrational number. When given finite |l|, the inf of error will be positive.
